# JavaScript from array to HTML string

Tags: javascript, arrays

*Can anyone please help me to solve this JavaScript task?*

I have to implement a JavaScript function that takes an array and returns the generated HTML string.

example: *[tagName, child1, child2, ...]*

• The tag name is always the first entry in the array and is a string.

• The children can be either arrays or strings.

• If the child is a string it is treated as plain text, not HTML markup.

• If the child is an array it is treated as a nested element.

• There is no support for attributes, comments, etc., just elements and text.

• Empty tags should be self-closing.

• Consecutive text nodes are merged in the finished output.

• **No libraries, build processes or transpilers**.

Examples:

```
['div']                       => '<div/>'

['h1', 'Text']                => '<h1>Text</h1>'

['span', 'More', 'Text']      => '<span>MoreText</span>'

['a', ['b', 'More'], ' Text'] => '<a><b>More</b> Text</a>'

['p', '<b>Text</b>']          => '<p>&lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;</p>'
```

This is my code so far, it uses objects instead of arrays. Any idea how to convert it?

```
var obj = {
  "h1": 'text',
  "a": {"b": 'more'}, // nested element
  "text": '', // empty tag
  "p": '<b>text</b>' // with HTML
};

var finalString = '';

function createHTML(obj){
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 

    if (obj[prop] == '[object Object]') {

      finalString += "<" + prop + ">";
      createHTML(obj[prop]);
      finalString += "</" + prop + ">";

    } else {
      if (obj[prop] == '') {
        finalString += "<" + prop + "/>";
      } else {
        finalString += "<" + prop + ">" + encodeURI(obj[prop]) + "</" + prop + ">";
      }
    }
  } 
}
}

createHTML(obj);

console.log(finalString);
// "<h1>text</h1><a><b>more</b></a><text/><p>%3Cb%3Etext%3C/b%3E</p>"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please post the code that you tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a coding service. Please add the code you have tried, and the problems that you might be having with it to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and [give it a go](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: you need a *type check* for object and just call the function with that object as result, like `if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') { finalstring += createHTML(obj[prop]); }` for a recursion call of the same function with different parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some recursive approach:

1. By generating DOM element object :

```js
function genMarkup(arr) {
  // create a dom element object with first array item
  var ele = document.createElement(arr[0]);
  // iterate over the remaining elements
  arr.slice(1).forEach(function(v) {
    // if item is array then call the function recursively
    // and append the returned element
    if (Array.isArray(v))
      ele.appendChild(genMarkup(v));
    // else generate a text node and append
    else
      ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
  })
  // return the element reference
  return ele;
}


[['div'],['h1', 'Text'],['span', 'More', 'Text'],['a', ['b', 'More'], ' Text'],['p', '<b>Text</b>']].forEach(function(d) {
  // get the outerHTML property to get the html content
  console.log(JSON.stringify(d) + ' => ' + genMarkup(d).outerHTML);
})
```

---

2. With simple string concatenation.

```js
function genMarkup(arr) {
  // generate opening tag
  var str = '<' + arr[0] + '>';
  // iterate over the remaining elements
  arr.slice(1).forEach(function(v) {
    // if item is array then call the function recursively
    // and append the returned value
    if (Array.isArray(v))
      str += genMarkup(v);
    // else concatenate the string
    else
      str += v.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  })
  // return the  result with the closing tag
  return str + '</' + arr[0] + '>';
}


[['div'],['h1', 'Text'],['span', 'More', 'Text'],['a', ['b', 'More'], ' Text'],['p', '<b>Text</b>']].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(d) + ' => ' + genMarkup(d));
})
```

Comment: Fantastic solution, so clever. Thank you so much!

Comment: @arthuruk :  glad to help :)

Comment: great solution +1 for that

Comment: In order to respect the specifications, I would add `.outerHTML.replace(/<(.*?)><\/\1>/,'<$1/>')`  (convert `<div></div>` to `<div/>`)